# Acting algebraically

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group that acts on some non empty set $V$.
What does it mean that $G$ acts algebraically on $V$?

I am well aware of the definition of being algebraic. But I cant find the definition about what it means to act algebraically anywhere.

Comment: Is G an *algebraic* group? Is V a variety?

Comment: Is $V$ a vector space (or does it have some other algebraic structure)?

Comment: In my specific case $V$ is a toric variety. I just asked the question more generally as I thought it wouldn't change the meaning?   Also in my specific case $G=N/N'$ is a finite group and N is a lattice (free abelian group) where N' is a sublattice of finite index.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the Wikipedia article on [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). Such an action can have additional properties. From Wikipedia: "In addition to continuous actions of topological groups on topological spaces, one also often considers smooth actions of Lie groups on smooth manifolds, regular actions of algebraic groups on algebraic varieties, and actions of group schemes on schemes. All of these are examples of group objects acting on objects of their respective category."